# Is it possible to do SLAAC with Route Advertisement *without* default-route?

Tags: ipv6

I have a router with IPv6-ULA networks. It's running Linux with Systemd-networkd if that matters.

Now I'd like to auto-configure clients in one network so that they will have an address in one of the ULA-prefixes. I have a config like this on that LAN:

```
[Network]
Description=My IPv6 local-only LAN, no internet access here!
VLAN=myvlan
LinkLocalAddressing=ipv6
LLDP=no
EmitLLDP=no
IPv6AcceptRA=no
IPv6SendRA=yes

[Address]
# For IPv4 local-only connectivity
Address=10.1.2.1/24

[IPv6SendRA]
EmitDNS=no
EmitDomains=no

[IPv6Prefix]
# Prefix 1337 from my random ULA prefix announced here
Prefix=fd58:22a0:d6b5:1337::/64
```

It works well, except for one thing... clients set a default route on the link-local address.

So, on clients, I see this:

```
# ip -6 route
[...]
fd58:22a0:d6b5:1337::/64 dev wlp2s0 proto kernel metric 256 expires 2591901sec pref medium
fe80::/64 dev wlp2s0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
default via fe80::36e6:d7ff:fe1b:48fe dev wlp2s0 proto ra metric 1024 expires 1701sec pref medium
```

The last line there I did not expect and it breaks things, because these hosts now think they can reach the whole IPv6-internet on this link, but they can't.

Before I start looking into Systemd-specific things, here's my main question more generally speaking: Is it even possible to do a Route-Advertisement **without** a default route as per IPv6-spec?

In Wireshark I've compared the Route-Announces with the ones my ISP router is sending to clients (supposed to add a default route) and I only noticed the difference in the managed-flag (because it does DHCPv6 as well) and some Prf-priority set to high instead of medium by Systemd. It makes me believe that clients set up a default route implicitly here. Without a global address and just an ULA that does not sound like something you want to do implictly, especially in multi-homed scenarios (one internet-enabled network, one private-only).

Comment: "_t works well, except for one thing... clients set a default route on the link-local address._" Yes, all networks on a link have the gateway set to the router's link-local address. That is how IPv6 RAs (Router Advertisements) work, so all networks advertised on the link are in the RAs, and all use the router's link-local address as the gateway. Unfortunately, host configurations are off-topic here. You can ask about your host on [su].

Comment: @RonMaupin Uhm, I believe we have a misunderstanding here. My question is conceptually: Can I send RAs without advertising a default route (only specific prefixes)?

Comment: That depends on the router model and configuration. Certainly, the on-topic enterprise-grade routers can do the, but your off-topic consumer-grade router may or may not be able to do that. Typically, consumer-grade devices will always send a default route because they assume they are connecting to the public Internet, and that needs a default route.

Comment: This has literally nothing to do with consumer grade things, but is about IPv6 standards and my example was with Linux. I've got an answer by now, thanks to @Ricky pointing me in the right direction. Unable to post as answer due to off-topic mark, though. **Conceptually speaking, the default route choice is determined by the lifetime advertisement and Prf flags. See [RFC4191](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4191). Solved.**

Comment: An on-topic, enterprise-grade router can be configured to advertise, or not, a default route. A host OS (also off-topic) may simply install a default route in the host, regardless of the RAs. What your consumer-grade router does is off-topic here, as is any host OS. So, yes, IPv6 can send RAs without a default route, but there are other factors to consider.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how systemD (or netplan) deals with this. But `radvd` supports setting the default lifetime value:

```
   AdvDefaultLifetime seconds

          The lifetime associated with the default router in units of sec-
          onds.  The maximum value corresponds to 18.2 hours.  A  lifetime
          of  0  indicates  that  the  router  is not a default router and
          should not appear on the default router list.  The router  life-
          time  applies  only  to  the  router's  usefulness  as a default
          router; it does not apply to information contained in other mes-
          sage fields or options.  Options that need time limits for their
          information include their own lifetime fields.

          Must be either zero or between MaxRtrAdvInterval and  9000  sec-
          onds.

          Default: 3 * MaxRtrAdvInterval (Minimum 1 second).
```

Comment: `A  lifetime of  0  indicates  that  the  router  is not a default router` Oh, wow, I did not expect such behavior to be part of a lifetime setting. o.O

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction! It's RFC4191 what I was looking for.